# Is there a way to sum a list based on another list?

Tags: python

Python 3 sum a list of time based on dates from another list.

I used the mentioned code to arrive at the total time, but I am trying to  aggregation the time for each dates. e.g. '02-01-2019' should sum up to '08:00:00'.

```
Date = ['01-01-2019', '02-01-2019', '02-01-2019']

Time = ['07:00:00', '06:00:00','02:00:00']


total = 0
for t in Time:   
    h, m, s = map(int, t.split(":"))
    total += 3600*h + 60*m + s
    d="%02d:%02d:%02d" % (total / 3600, total / 60 % 60, total % 60)
```

I need an if statement to check if the sum of time for each date>='08:00:00'.

e.g

```
if time_for_each_date>='08:00:00':

   do something

else do something else.
```

Comment: You will need to convert the times to a tractable format, such as the `datetime` package.  Then you can add the times and convert back to your preferred string format.  Gathering all the times for one date is a well-documented technique; you should be able to make some sort of attack on this to post here.  "I can't figure out how to design my program" is off-topic; you'll need to meet us part way there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help get you started on accomplishing your ultimate goal:

```
Date = ['01-01-2019', '02-01-2019', '02-01-2019']

Time = ['07:00:00', '06:00:00','02:00:00']

import datetime

data = zip(Date, Time)

dates = []

for d in data:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("{}, {}".format(*d), "%m-%d-%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    dates.append(dt)

totals = {}
for d in dates:
    if d.date() not in totals: totals[d.date()] = d.hour
    else: totals[d.date()] += d.hour

for date, time in totals.items():
    if time >= 8:
        # do something
        print('do something:', date)
    else:
        print('do something else.')
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfect. I had to tweak it a bit to achieve what I was looking for.